# How to append a filter to a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have assigned a jquery selector to a variable. Now I am trying to append the ":checked" filter to that. Is there anyway where I can append to my variable "options"?

Thanks!

```
  var options= $('input[class*=menuoptions_limit_options_for{$cat_id}]');
  options.on('click', function(){
      var \$checked_items_maxed = options.(':checked').length <= {$max_checkbox_allowed};
```

Comment: `options.filter(':checked')`

Comment: You should not use a backslash in variable name, it's an **illegal character**.

Comment: Thanks Arun. Marin this code was copied and pasted from a php file. That's why there is a backslash